# Get unique n permutations with randomly selected r

Tags: python

Consider this list:

```py
from string import ascii_lowercase

a = list(ascii_lowercase)
```

I want to get `n` number of **unique** permutations of `a` with maximum of `r` values in it, which is randomly selected between `1-r` in each item.

Example output for `n=10, r=2`:

```
[['e', 'z'],
 ['q'],
 ['r', 'g'],
 ['c'],
 ['p'],
 ['o', 'j'],
 ['i'],
 ['d'],
 ['e'],
 ['z']]
```

I wrote this function for this:

```py
def get_permutations(arr, n: int, r: int) -> List[List[str]]:
    """
    Get random permutations of given array with no duplicates.

    Each permutation should contain 1 - r elements randomly chosen from arr.

    Parameters
    ----------
    n : int
        The number of permutations.
    r : int
        The maximum number of items in a permutation.

    Returns
    -------
    A list of permutations.

    """
    perms = []

    hashables = set()

    while True:
        perm = random.choices(arr, k=random.randint(1,r))
        
        # convert list to string so we can store it in a set
        hashable = ''.join(perm)
        if  hashable not in hashables:
            perms.append(perm)
            hashables.add(hashable)

        if len(perms) == n:
            return perms
```

So I did this task with not using hashing, it takes ~15 seconds. But I wanted to optimize it.

In my task, I'm going to have a `a` with length of ~1500, `n=20_000` and `r=3`.

I can reach up to `n=18000` at it tooks ~1 seconds. But `n=20_000` never completes. In fact, I can run it with `n=18_200` and it takes ~1.2 seconds but `n=18_300` never completes. I don't understand how.

Here is the profile of the functions with `n=18_200`:
[image]

Any suggestions on this task and this performance issue? I can rewrite `get_permutations` if needed. Thanks.

Comment: Why not use `itertools`?

Comment: `itertools.permutations` is great but it retuns permutations in an order every time. I can shuffle `a` every time but I still need to check if it's unique, which I think consumes most the time.

Comment: Could it be that you're exhausting the number of possible permutations?  You have `if  hashable not in hashables:` so if every permutation that gets created already exists, your loop will run forever.

Comment: `k=random.randint(1,r)`  -- doesn't this bias the choices of the permutation towards permutations with smaller `k`? Larger `k` have more permutations, so if you want uniform sampling of the valid permutations, you can't use a uniform choice for `k`.

Comment: @defladamouse you are a genius. For this test case I used `ascii_lowercase` so it has very few unique values, so it's exhausting, yes... In real case I will have ~1500 unique values. Please write an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @JohnColeman yes you're actually right. Never thought of that. But it's not a major issue right now. Thank you for pointing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to come from this part of the code:

```py
    if  hashable not in hashables:
            perms.append(perm)
            hashables.add(hashable)
```

There is a limited number of permutations available and, if you reach that limit, this `if` statement will never pass and the main `while` loop will run forever.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should not use `''.join(perm)` to get a hashable version of your permutation. You should add a separator (like `'|'.join(perm)`) between each elements.
Otherwise, `['a', 'b']` and `['ab']` would have the same hash.

I just tried with your values and it works fine, what elements are in your array ?

```py
size = 1500
n = 18300
r = 3
a = [str(i) for i in range(size)]

start = time.time()
get_permutations(a, n, r)
print(f"Done in {time.time()-start} seconds")
```

```
>>> Done in 0.06795191764831543 seconds
```

Comment: Yea that's a good point. In real case I will have ~1500 unique elements. My testing array was bad. The problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't answer your question directly, but if you want to sample the permutations uniformly from the set of possible permutations, you can tweak how you pick the `k`:

```
import random, math

def randK(n,r,weights = None):
    if weights is None:
        perm_weights = [math.perm(n,k) for k in range(1,r+1)]
    else:
        perm_weights = weights
    return random.choices(range(1,r+1),weights = perm_weights)[0]
```

It is important to note that `n` in this function is the number of items in the set being sampled from (`len(arr)` in your code) and not the number of random permutations generated.

This might actually help with the efficiency, since the hit-or-miss approach will involve more missing with smaller `k`. For maximum efficiency, you could compute `perm_weights` once, outside of your main loop and then pass it in as the optional argument. Note that `randK(n,r,[1]*r)` will reduce to uniform choice.

Comment: Good call, but I believe in my situation higher number of permutations are more likely to get seleced. I mean, ~1500 permutations will have 1 item, ~2m will have 2 and ~34b will have 3. But in your weights, the higher value of r values has even more likely to be choosed. With uniqueness constraint, I think I would never have evenly distributed 20k permutations because `p(len(arr), 1)` is the limit here, which is 1500.

Comment: I would try `perm_weights[::-1]` but it maybe never will be completed in my situation.

Comment: @emremrah It of course depends on what you are trying to do. You are trying to pick permutations uniformly from the set of permutations with length <= r then `perm_weights` are the appropriate weights -- but in that case the number of longer permutations will dwarf the number of smaller permutations, so you will mostly see long permutations. What you want seems to be a stratified random sample rather than a simple random sample. The `weights` argument could be used to weight the strata however you want. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stratified_sampling for some ideas.

Comment: Luckily, at least permutations with `r > 1` are likely to be close to each other (for my case), because P(1500, 2) >> 20000.